# Subclassing dict and nested dicts in it

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, overriding, subclass

I have a nested dictionary that I want to convert to the following subclass I did:

```
class SubDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.keys():
            return self.get(attr)
```

And if I do, it works great for the base dict :

```
my_nested_dict = SubDict(my_nested_dict)
```

But I need the nested ones converted to SubDict too. How could I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: "Solved" it by adding `attr = self.get(attr); return SubDict(attr) if isinstance(attr, dict) else attr` to the code. sorry for the bother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recurse over the nested dictionaries and convert those recursively:

```
class SubDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SubDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        for key, value in self.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self[key] = SubDict(value)
```

Have you looked into [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) at all? You can create a tree from scratch with that quite easily:

```
import defaultdict

def Tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

Comment: @Megaslav: You are doing the same thing, only on retrieving and every time, my code does it on instantiation and once.

Comment: You are right Martijin, great code! That is what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your `SubDict` class does nothing other than what you show here, this is a job for `defaultdict` [as document by Harold Cooper on Github](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250):

```
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

Comment: I use it to retrieve values in the dict.key.sub_dict_key.sub_sub_dict_key fashion. The defaultdict doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: Tink I read over the fact that you're using `__getattr__` in stead of `__init__`, so my answer isn't that great (the defaultdict *is* though :))